# Converting loss in fuel economy to gain in fuel consumption

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem: A truck's initial fuel consumption is $\frac{1}{8}$ L/km. The truck loses $\frac{1}{10}$ km/L in fuel economy due to poor maintenance. What is the truck's new fuel consumption?

The difficulty is that the initial gas mileage is stated in terms of fuel consumption, whereas the loss in gas mileage is stated in terms of fuel economy, so you can't simply subtract—you have to convert one to the other.

I find it easy to convert fuel consumption to fuel economy; it's just the reciprocal really: $\frac{1}{8}$ L/km (fuel consumption) is just 8 km/L (equivalent fuel economy). Then you can do $8-0.1=7.9$ km/L.

But trying it from the opposite perspective—converting the *reduction* in fuel economy to an increase in fuel consumption—I'm finding quite confusing; it's not a simple reciprocal. That is, if the truck loses $\frac{1}{10}$ km for every litre consumed, then surely it doesn't consume 10 extra litres of gas for every km it travels?

Any hints/help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it like this.

Initially the truck consumed $\frac{1}{8}$ L/km, or equivalently $10$ litres per $80$ kilometer. Now it loses $\frac{1}{10}$ km/L or equivalently $1$ km per 10 litres. Therefore it can now travel $79$ kilometers in $10$ litres or at $\frac{1}{7.9}$ L/km. Does that answer your question?

---

To answer your question of "Losing how many L/km = how much gain in km/L" time for some algebra. Let the original mileage be $x$ km/L. Now if we lose $y$ L/km. New mileage by above method = $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}-y} = \frac{x}{1-xy}$

Change = $x - \frac{x}{1-xy} = \frac{x-x^2y-x}{1-xy} = \frac{x^2y}{1-xy}$

Direct conversion(as you wanted to) would mean the final expression is independent of $x$ which it isn't.

Comment: Well it's a good answer but doesn't answer my question specifically, which is, "How do you convert a loss expressed in terms of km/L into an equivalent *gain* expressed in terms of L/km. In other words, losing 0.1 km/L is equivalent to gaining how many L/km?

Comment: @yroc how about now?

Comment: Ah, so you've demonstrated that it's impossible to convert a loss of km/L into a gain in L/km without taking into account the original km/L. That's interesting and I wouldn't have expected that -- I definitely need to think about that more. Thanks!

Comment: @yroc you're welcome. :)